# Network card (link-status LED) still active after shutdown from Windows 7 (but not from XP)

Tags: windows-7, power, network-adapter, shutdown

When I shut down Windows 7, my NIC remains active and the link status LED on the router remains lit. When I shut down Windows *XP*, it does **not**. Further, *rebooting* XP causes the NIC to shutdown as well, while rebooting Windows 7 leaves it active.

It is *not* a hardware configuration issue (eg WOL setting in BIOS—which for the record is disabled) because like I said, it does indeed turn off when XP is shut down. The issue is with Windows 7.

Yes, I have already changed the settings (figure 1) for the network card in *Device Manager* to disable all `Wake-on-LAN`, `Magic-Packet`, etc. settings as well as checking the `Allow computer to turn off this device` option in the *Power Management* tab. I have done this in both XP and 7. (The (default) Windows 7 drivers seem to have more options than the (again default) Windows XP drivers.)

I did find plenty of hits about this issue, but not surprisingly, most of them just said to turn WOL off (and yet a lot of the askers said they already did). Strangely enough, [one person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51902/nic-stays-on-after-shutdown) actually complained that their NIC stays on in Ubuntu but turns *off* in Windows 7. I have the opposite issue in 7.

I have set the standby state to S3 in the BIOS instead of S1 and also used `dumppo` to set the minimum standby state to S3 in both XP and 7. Examining the power-setting differences (figure 2), I do not see anything relevant to the network adapter, so I am at a loss as to why 7 would force the NIC to remain active.

**Update**:
Just to add to the confusion, I have noticed that when I put Windows 7 into standby/sleep mode, the link-LED turns off. So Windows 7 *is* capable of shutting the NIC off, and does so when put to sleep, but for some reason does not do so when shut down.

**Figure 1:** NIC driver settings in XP and 7

[image: NIC driver settings]

**Figure 2:** `dumppo` differences between XP and 7

[image: dumppo differences]

Comment: What kind of computer is this? Notebook or a PC?  What kind (if it's a PC how about a motherboard model)?   So far it just sounds like 7 is [using ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#OSPM_responsibilities) differently than XP for the S5 state (if that's in fact what you are going into when you 'shutdown').  Have you tried a BIOS upgrade?

Comment: Desktop. I have set the BIOS to use only S3 for suspend (S1 left the fans and stuff on), but I don’t use suspend anyway; I usually just do a full shutdown to S5.

Comment: Do you have a dual boot with win7/xp, or two identical hardware machines? What NIC is it, and what driver versions is installed in Win7 and XP? For example some versions of intel Pro NIC's have different options based on driver version. Potentially one of those options/default settings could help if you identified it.

Comment: It’s the same system. I’m using the on-board 3Com NIC with the default drivers from Windows. I’ve taken screenshots of every option in *Device Manager* in XP and will cross-reference them with the ones in 7 because I think 7 may have a few more options than in XP (though I have definitely set every WOL related one to off).

Comment: Since I posted this question, the original motherboard I was using (P4P800SE) died (one of the voltage-regulator ICs literally burned out and the plastic melted). I replaced the board with a similar one (P4P800). One of the only differences was the onboard NIC was 3Com instead of Marvell. This problem did not manifest and I forgot about it. Recently, I found another P4P800SE and swapped it back in and now the onboard NIC (a Marvell again) is exhibiting the behavior again. However now, XP does not work; when I shutdown from XP, the NIC LEDs remain active as does the LED on its router port. ಠ_ఠ