# Wake-on-lan from S5 and prevent network card from turning off

Tags: windows-7, bios, power-management, wake-on-lan

I'm tired googling and looking through hundreds of forums, please help.
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Motherboard: ASUS M4A77T/USB3
Onboard network card: Realtek® 8112L

The problem is that network card keeps turning off when I shut down my computer. Although I've seen many PCs with network LEDs keeping flashing after shutting down. I set all required BIOS and Windows power settings as it was said in many manuals by network card keeps turning off. In motherboard specifications it's not directly said that WOL is supported but I thought motherboards such as mine shoud support. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you’ve configured the BIOS settings, do you mean you set the [BIOS option](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4A77T/E5248_M4A77T.pdf) `Power on From S5 By Ring` in the section `Power → APM Configuration`? When you say you’ve configured the Windows settings, do you mean you set the [WoL setting in the *Advanced* tab](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-l-TaQQLMojg/TXyRkuikJtI/AAAAAAAAAIQ/DBSh3ggNY24/s1600/Wake+on+Magic+Packet.png) of the network-adapter’s *Device Manager* properties-dialog (which can have a wide variety of wording and have more than one related setting)?

Comment: @Synetech yes, all that settings are enabled

Comment: I have the [opposite problem](http://superuser.com/questions/389107/network-card-link-status-led-still-active-after-shutdown-from-windows-7-but-n) as you. While looking for a solution to that, I had found a page that says Windows 7 turns the NIC off, but that wasn’t what they were asking to fix, so it probably can’t help you. Do you have a router? If so, can you observe the link-status LED of the port that your system is plugged into?

Comment: @Synetech yes, it's off :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to enable it! It took several months!
I've updated my Realtek drivers to the newest version and checked (enabled) all checkboxes on Power Management tab despite everyone had advised to uncheck them. 
It's strange because I had gone through all possible combinations of settings and I'm almost sure I've tried this one. So in case I missed anything, feel free to ask in comments and I will share all necassary power management settings with you. Good luck!